# jpackage on windows makes program silently doing nothing

Tags: jpackage

I'm trying to learn to use jpackage, and I can create an installer for a simple program, but the installed program then does nothing.
Here is what I did:
-make the most standard hello world program

```
package hello;
public class World {
  public static void main(String[]a){
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    throw new Error("Nothing is happening");
  }
}
```

turn it into a Jar, save the jar as helloFolder/HelloWorld.jar

run the following command:

```
C:\..\Java16>jdk-16.0.2\bin\jpackage 
  --name helloWorldApp
  --input helloFolder
  --main-jarHelloWorld.jar
  --main-class hello.World
```

See that there is a file helloWorldApp.exe in the folder.
Double click on it. An installation starts, with zero feedback.
Exploring the file system, I can see the installed program.
Going into the folder and running the 'app' does absolutely nothing.

```
cd C:\"Program Files"\helloWorldApp
C:\Program Files\helloWorldApp>helloWorldApp.exe

C:\Program Files\helloWorldApp>
```

As you can see, no prints, no error message.
At this point I have many questions:

1)- What is happening? why the program is not running but there is no error message anywhere?

2)- Why there is no feedback during the installation? it would be nice to have the most standard 'do you want a desktop shortcut' or similar stuff

3)- Can I make a portable exe instead of an installer one?

4)- (RANT) why I need to be on win to make a win installer, and on Linux to make a Linux installer? do I have to run VMs with different systems to automatize my deployment?

Comment: Your application is a console application; try including the `--win-console` flag when invoking `jpackage` and then you should see output. If you want the user to be able to choose where to install then use `--win-dir-chooser`. There's also `--win-menu` / `--win-menu-group` and `--win-shortcut`, though I don't know if those options will ask the user to confirm. Also, all those options are Windows-specific; I don't know what options are available for Mac/Linux.

Comment: Note `jpackage` has a [user guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/jpackage/preface.html#GUID-C8F52DC6-0750-497D-9DAB-2F88E10787BE).

Comment: added --win-console, nothing changes.

Comment: Assuming I didn't make a mistake, I can't _quite_ reproduce your problem. With a modular application I saw output, including the error's stack trace. Yet when I switched to a non-modular application I no longer saw output, but a dialog did pop up saying "Failed to launch JVM".

Comment: Interesting, I'm going for the non modular here. Also, note that the JDK I'm using is NOT the one 'installed'